# mathsf font incorrect in ShareLaTeX using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, miktex, sharelatex

The `mathsf` font does not seem to be implemented correctly in ShareLaTeX when you compile in XeLaTeX. I selected as main text font Arial, which is correctly displayed for the normal text in my document. I have some TiKZ figures which contain expressions like `\mathsf{parameter}`. ShareLaTeX does not display this in the Arial font but in the standard `mathsf` font. I do not have this problem with MikTeX on my computer.
Does anyone know how to fix this issue on ShareLaTeX?

Comment: the difference is not miktex/sharelatex but in the package versions but you haven't said what packages you are using. Are you using `unicode-math` ?  You would not, by default, expect `\mathsf` to pick up the text font, although you could configure it that way. In any case if you add `\listfiles` to your document you could compare (and post here) the file lists on the two systems which should show any package differences.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am indeed using the package unicode-math. I checked the versions, MikTeX on my computer uses v0.8c dated 2015/09/29 by Will Robertson, while ShareLaTeX uses v0.7f dated 2014/06/30. That might explain the difference. Does somebody know how to update the package on ShareLaTeX?

Comment: Will almost completely re-wrote unicode-math this year (you can see the video of his talk at TUG2015.....)

Comment: Yes indeed, do you know how to use the most recent package version on ShareLaTeX?

Comment: I have no idea at all about sharelatex, sorry:-)